# Does POSIX define context switch?

Tags: thread

Is a *POSIX* [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) well-defined? Is it the same thing as switching threads in C? Can the C compiler generate everything for a context switch or is assembly programming still needed for a routine that switches the threads or switches the "context"? Is there even defined what is meant by "context" - isn't it the same as a thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX uses the term *context switch* for at least two different purposes, without attempting to define it rigorously (or even *providing* a definition):

- switching between *threads*, and
- switching between *processes*

Rather, POSIX assumes you already know what the term means. For instance,

> [3.118 CPU Time (Execution Time)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_118)
>
> The time spent executing a process or thread, including the time spent executing system services on behalf of that process or thread. If the Threads option is supported, then the value of the CPU-time clock for a process is implementation-defined. With this definition the sum of all the execution times of all the threads in a process might not equal the process execution time, even in a single-threaded process, because implementations may differ in how they account for time during ***context switches*** or for other reasons.

Further reading:

- [thread context switch vs process context switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440128/thread-context-switch-vs-process-context-switch)
- [system call and context switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238326/system-call-and-context-switch)
- [The Context-Switch Overhead Inflicted by Hardware
  Interrupts (and the Enigma of Do-Nothing Loops)](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/expcs07/papers/4-tsafrir.pdf), Dan Tsafrir
- [Verified Process-Context Switch for
  C-Programmed Kernels](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.475.4794&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Starostin and Tsyban